# How to redirect to new page on maintenance mode?

Tags: magento-1.9

I think I'm missing something. I attempted to do this the "proper" **magento 1.x** way:

- Copied `rootDir/errors/default` to `rootDir/errors/janitor`
- Changed `<skin>default</skin>` to `<skin>janitor</skin>`
- Updated code in `rootDir/errors/janitor/503.phtml` as needed.

This kind of works. The problem is the edits to `503.phtml` basically make it a new page. It sends headers, it has a full `<html> .. </html>` structure etc.

Obviously what ends up happening is `page.phtml` renders first, with the contents of `503.phtml` inside that page as the body.

I COULD completely change page.html but I would like to keep using the default for every other error (404, etc.)

The 503/maintenance page is a separate entity with its own markup, styles, logo and so forth.

Right now the solution is simply to bypass all this by changing the logic in `rootDir/index.php` to load my custom maintenance page rather than go through the standard magento error processing/rendering of 503.phtml.

Answer (score 2):

Magento goes to maintenance mode when you create a file named **maintenance.flag** to your Magento home directory. This is how Magento handles it:

```
$maintenanceFile = 'maintenance.flag';

if (file_exists($maintenanceFile)) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/errors/503.php';
    exit;
}
```

If you want to custom and design it, follow [this one](https://support.cloudways.com/create-magento-custom-maintenance-page/).